# App reading data after deleting files from Application Support folder

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I have just stumbled upon a very strange behaviour.

In my app I store all the information in the application support folder. During testing I often remove the files from that folder for app debugging which was working just fine until now. 
Like always I deleted the app folder in Application Support but after compiling (and cleaning) my app is still reading data from somewhere. And it is the correct data.

I have tried searching everywhere but my data files don't show up in any search on my mac. I have also tried restarting my mac but with no luck.

Has anybody ever experienced this or knows what the hell is happening here?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this one out. I had changed my app to be sandboxed and added entitlements. That means the application support direct is following:

```
/Users/<username>/Library/Containers/<com.company.appname>/Data/Library/Application Support/<appname>
```

It is very interesting that no finder search found that folder with my app's name.

I hope this helps somebody in the future.